# Need to extract date from a string column in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

Need to fetch all the rows in IBM DB2 which matches with the current date in IBM DB2.
There is no date column in the Table but there is a column which contains date in the value.

FileName : String1_11Nov20_String2
The value need to be extracted : `11Nov20`

Need an SQL something like below which passes current date inside like :

```
select * from Table where FileName like '%Current_date%'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your date values in strings have exactly the same month representation returned by the following query AND the day representation is with leading zeroes, then you may use the following expression in the `LIKE` predicate:
`LIKE '%\_' || TO_CHAR(CURRENT DATE, 'DDMonYY', 'en_US') || '\_%' ESCAPE '\'`

```
WITH T(I) AS (VALUES 1 UNION ALL SELECT I+1 FROM T WHERE I < 12)
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE('2020-' || DIGITS(DEC(I, 2)) || '-01'), 'DDMonYY', 'en_US')
FROM T;
```